# How to create new instance of ILaunchConfiguration or ILaunch?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

currently my plugin can be started by creating a corresponding launch configuration and then pressing "run". Now I want to extend the plugin so that it is possible to right click on files and run the plugin on the selected file. Extending the menu accordingly already works.

However, now I need to have an instance of ILaunchConfiguration (or at least an instance of ILaunch) to feed into my existing setup. This then grabs the process out of the ILaunch object and starts communicating.

How can I create a new ILaunchConfiguration based on known default settings and a specific input file? I do not see any public constructor I can use.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is the way to obtain an `ILaunchConfiguration`:

```java
ILaunchManager mgr = DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager();
ILaunchConfigurationType lct = mgr.getLaunchConfigurationType(IOpcodeConstants.LAUNCH_CFG_TYPE);
ILaunchConfiguration[] lcs = mgr.getLaunchConfigurations(lct);
```