# Creating Eclipse debug configuration without GUI

Tags: eclipse, debugging, ide, configuration-files, internals

I have X number of test input files for a python program and for each file, I want to generate debug configuration for each input file in Eclipse skipping the painful process of clicks.

Does anybody know which directory/file Eclipse internally uses to store the debug configuration especially the argument to the program?

Comment: eclipse community seems to be lil inactive on SO :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the Debug Configuration for the launch that is stored in a `xxx.launch` file in the workspace `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches` directory.

Eclipse has extensive APIs for launch configurations, see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915810/how-to-create-new-instance-of-ilaunchconfiguration-or-ilaunch)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958449/using-pythontidy-with-eclipse  can you help me with this question too?